# Getting blank string when trying to print a paragraph using selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

After opening [Website](https://www.globalsqa.com/demo-site/frames-and-windows/#iFrame) I'm switching frames and click on the first image shown below. On the next page, I want to print any one paragraph under the title **Selenium 3.0 Training**. But I'm getting an empty response in the console. Please help. [image]

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\nehra\\newSeleniumWorkspace\\tryypanda\\chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
    
    driver.get("https://www.globalsqa.com/demo-site/frames-and-windows/#iFrame");
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    WebElement iframe1=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"post-2632\"]/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/p/iframe"));
    driver.switchTo().frame(iframe1);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"portfolio_items\"]/div[1]/a/div/div/div[1]/img")).click();
    driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
    driver.switchTo().frame("globalSqa");
    String getparatext=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"wrapper\"]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/p[1]/span")).getText();
    System.out.println(getparatext);
}
```

`

Answer (score 0):

Issue: text was getting visible only after the screen was scrolled. So, adding a mouse scroll event after switching frames helped me.

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,250)", "");
```